# What is a secure and reliable alternative to Skype?

Tags: software-recommendation, skype, voip

I've been browsing the Internet for quite a while on the search for an alternative to Skype.
Since I'm looking for a cross-platform program, I chose Jitsi for a start but found that it works quite unreliable (e.g. shuts down when receiving a call) and lacks some technical sophistication as well (e.g. produces echos, stops transmission for seconds during a call). Thus it's not what I'm looking for.

Is there some program you can recommend (Linux - Linux/Linux - Windows)?
I'd really like to avoid using Skype as a last resort.

Comment: What's wrong with skype?

Comment: @Tim What's right with Skype?

Comment: Many people use it (it is the know product for webcam calling - I'll skype you later), It works, it is cross platform and easy to install.

Comment: @Tim The problem of the current skype implementation is: You won't see the online users if you run it only in the taskbar.

Comment: @Tim: Articles like [this](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2474090/data-privacy/new-snowden-revelation-shows-skype-may-be-privacy-s-biggest-enemy.html) made me question whether I'd like to support Skype any longer. However, I know how comfortable it is, no doubt about that.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+security+flaws) and [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=computer+security+flaws). The internet is a security issue, essentially everything is either currently vulnerable, or will be at some point. Just saying :)

Comment: You're right and I'm aware of that. But even if using another client only provides a shallow feeling of security and self-determination, that's good enough for me. ,-)

Answer (score 4):

Both Teamspeak and Mumble are in my opinion better than Skype. They use less resources than Skype but require a server to run.

So either you set up a server yourself or you find an open server.

Teamspeak and Mumble are basically the same, both require a server to run and both have better sound quality than Skype. They are both available for different platforms although Mumble has better support for Linux.

They have different security options. You can put a server password so that only some users may get onto the server, or you can set different user levels so only some users may enter specific rooms. Both models are good, but I prefer the user levels since this allows everyone to access and use some rooms and also gives specific users more private rooms.

Both Teamspeak and Mumble are popular in Clan games, since it's easy to connect to a server and find people to talk to.

More information about both programs can be found below,

- [**Teamspeak**](http://www.teamspeak.com/)
- [**Mumble**](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 3):

I use [google hangouts](https://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/), it runs in browser.

You do have to install a program, but it is cross platform. You have to have a google account.

Comment: Can Google hangouts use voice only? Or does it require a web-camera?

Comment: Can do either. I normally just do voice - I use it as a telephone to people in Kenya with slow internet.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But referring to our discussion above I have to say that choosing Google to replace Microsoft because of privacy concerns doesn't seem to be a big step forward.

Comment: Well no, but I'm not convinced about what you are worried about... But fair enough, google isn't that *trustworthy*

Answer (score 1):

As an another alternative, there is viber. I didn't try, but if you use it on your phone, it can be useful. It only supports 64-bit systems on linux. You can install 32-bit version through wine but I dont recommend using wine for this.

http://www.viber.com/

Comment: any links? Is it available for multiple platforms? How does it work?

Comment: http://www.viber.com/
It works on almost every mobile platform and desktop platforms. (As I say, for now 32-bit Linux systems doesn’t supported.) You can make calls, send texts and make video chats.

Comment: Why isn't this and more in your answer? At least I wont up vote an incomplete answer...

Comment: I just forget adding link to my answer. And I said, I didnt try it, so I don't wanna misinform you.

Comment: aah, an answer with a link, up vote!